# Finding the theoretical mean and variance

Tags: variance, expected-value

This should be a simple question, and I tried working it out but I am unsure if this is correct.

**What I want to find:**

I am investigating the a 1-dimentional biased random walk as the number of steps N and the probability of it moving to the right (it being a 1) P

I have to Compute the theoretical mean and variance for N = 1, 50, 100, 150, ..., 1000, and p = 0.5, 0.6, ..., 1.

**From what I understand I have to use the following formula:**

`Sum(x*p(x))` for each value x can take on.

Since x can take on -1 or 1 and for there being only 1 trial on the first N, and the first probability is 0.5: I would get 0, because the probability of getting either 1 or -1 is 50%. But how can I do this if N = 50? Would I just use the same formula and sum it N(i) times. (so if i == 2, N = 50 so I would do `Sum(x*p(x))` 50 times?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Binomial distribution?

Comment: If you want to google, "weighted random walk" (with or without quotes) might help.